# How to force enter key to make a line break inside iframe editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am trying to learn how to make a text editor using javascript(I am new to JavaScript).Here I create a paragraph using "para" button and inside the paragraph there will be a quote.Every time I press 'enter' within this paragraph, a new paragraph is created, rather than a new line for typing texts. How can I force a line break  to be created instead of a paragraph element?also if I clicked outside of the quotation mark it wont allow me to write inside the paragraph

```
<script>
    function loads(){
        idContent.document.designMode="On";
    }

    function para(){
        var m=document.createElement("p");
        m.setAttribute('style',"border:1px solid black;height:100px;width:500px;position:relative;background-color:white;");   
        m.setAttribute('designMode',"on");
        m.setAttribute('contenteditable',"true");   
        var t=document.createElement("q");
        t.innerHTML="quote here";   
        m.appendChild(t);
        idContent.document.body.appendChild(m);
    }
</script>
```

Here is my html code,

```
<body onLoad="loads();" style="position:relative;">
    <iframe id="idContent" width="600" height="280" contenteditable="true" ></iframe>
    <input type="button" value="para" onClick="para();">
</body>
```

Here is my css styles,

```
<style>
    * {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    q {
        color:;
    }

    #idContent{
        background-color:pink;
    }

    div{
        border:1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You're testing with IE?

Comment: no.i am using opera currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function appendPara(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {  //13 is javascript key-code for Enter
        .....
        idContent.document.body.appendChild(m);    
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i am trying to fill the text field on pressing enter key.problem is i can not write outside of the quote and even wnen i press enter key another new paragraph is created .if i press backspace to delete it, it gets back again inside the quote.how can i prevent creating new paragraphs on pressing enter key?

Comment: @user3138436 If that is the case, you just need to add `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `q` is not a general purpose HTML element ( if you go out of quotes, you will not be able to edit ) try a `div`:

```
function para(){
    var m=document.createElement("p");
    m.setAttribute('style',"border:1px solid black;height:100px;width:500px;position:relative;background-color:white;");   
    m.setAttribute('designMode',"on");
    m.setAttribute('contenteditable',"true");   
    var t=document.createElement("div"); //"div" instead of "q"
    t.innerHTML="\"quote here\"";   
    m.appendChild(t);
    idContent.document.body.appendChild(m);
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HariprasadKamath/kjw9A/) is the fiddle

Comment: thanks..that can be a solution.but my main prob is on pressing enter key another para is created.how can it be prevented?

Comment: See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HariprasadKamath/kjw9A/). I think it's fixed. At least in my chrome.

Comment: @Hariprasad What you mean [`q`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q) being not a HTML element?

Comment: It's a short quotation. I meant to say it's not general purpose element.

Comment: @Hariprasad : your fiddle is not working, can u plz get back 
Error : Cannot set property 'designMode' of undefined
3fiddle.jshell.net/:60 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined